# Excel like autofilter in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've gone through many article in google regarding this, but couldn't find a proper solution

I've a `gridview` & `dropdownlists` of distinct columns . All the dropdownlist data are mutually dependent on each other dropdownlist (just like how we have in Excel Filter). Based on these dropdownlist values, Gridview will be populated.

Please guide on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very cludgy, because GridViews aren't very flexible outside of the functionality they're already programmed for. If I were you, I'd just write HTML tables directly. But if you insist...

I wrote the markup for my GridView on my .aspx page. I also created Panel controls that contained the DropDownList controls for searching. In the code behind, I removed the Panel controls from their parent and placed them in the Controls collection of the header row in the appropriate column of the GridView.

Here's an example panel...

```
<!-- Panels that are moved into the CallType column header -->
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="CallTypeSortFilterPanel">
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="CallTypeSortBtn" OnClick="SortBtn_Click" Text="Call Type" ToolTip="The type of call you reported this as. (Click to sort)" /></td>
<td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="CallTypeSortAscArrow" OnClick="SortBtn_Click" ImageUrl="~/styles/asc.gif" Visible="false" ToolTip="Currently sorted Ascending. Click to sort descending." /><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="CallTypeSortDescArrow" ToolTip="Currently sorted descending. Click to sort ascending." OnClick="SortBtn_Click" ImageUrl="~/styles/desc.gif" Visible="false" /></td>
<td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="CallTypeFilterImg" AlternateText="Filter by Call Type" OnClientClick="ShowCallTypePanel(); return false;" ImageUrl="~/styles/filter-orange.gif" Width="25" Height="25" CssClass="FilterButton" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
<asp:Panel runat="server" style="position:relative;">
<!-- Absolutely positioned panel (non-modal popup style) http://forums.asp.net/t/1070385.aspx/1 -->
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="CallTypeFilterPanel" BackColor="White" style="display:none;Z-INDEX: 125; LEFT: 5px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 5px; width:200px" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Ridge">
        <h2>Call Type Filter</h2>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CallFilterCBL">
            <asp:ListItem Text="VoIP" Value="VoIP" Selected="True" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Cell Phone" Value="CellPhoneCall" Selected="True" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="VTC" Value="VTC" Selected="True" />
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="HideCallTypePanel(); return false;" Text="Cancel" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button runat="server" ID="CallTypeFilterOk" Text="OK" OnClick="FilterOk_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Here's the JavaScript (jQuery) for HideCallTypePanel()

```
function HideCallTypePanel() {
var calltypefilterpanel = '#<%= CallTypeFilterPanel.ClientID %>';
$(calltypefilterpanel).hide();
    }
```

Here's the code you'll call in your Page_Load method.

```
CallTypeSortFilterPanel.Parent.Controls.Remove(CallTypeSortFilterPanel);
DiscoveredCallsGV.HeaderRow.Cells[DiscoveredCallsGV.GetColumnIndex("CallType")].Controls.Add(CallTypeSortFilterPanel);
```

GridView.GetColumnIndex() is an extension method I wrote. You can replace it with hard coded column numbers, but here's the method if you want it.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Returns the index of a column with the specified DataField string (or SortExpression if TemplateField). Throws an exception if not found.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gv"></param>
        /// <param name="DataField"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int GetColumnIndex(this System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gv, string DataField)
            {
            foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField column in gv.Columns)
                {
                if (column.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField))
                    {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField bf = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField)column;
                    if (bf.DataField == DataField)
                        {
                        return gv.Columns.IndexOf(bf);
                        }
                    }
                else if (column.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField))
                    {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField hlf = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField)column;
                    if (hlf.SortExpression == DataField)
                        {
                        return gv.Columns.IndexOf(hlf);
                        }
                    }
                else if (column.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField))
                    {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField tf = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField)column;
                    if (tf.SortExpression == DataField)
                        {
                        return gv.Columns.IndexOf(tf);
                        }
                    }

                }
            throw new ApplicationException("Column " + DataField + " not found in GridView " + gv.ID);
            }
```

Edit- In case it wasn't clear, the FilterOk_Click function of the CallTypeFilterOk button is where you retrieve the filter values from all of your filter dropdowns, then execute your query with the new filters, and then bind the resulting data back to the GridView.

Comment: Can you please let me know how do I make mutual dependent dropdownlists?

Comment: In the above code, when you handle FilterOk_Click, just modify the the DropDownList you use for filtering with the valid options.